flutter local notifications on the background not working for iOS
So I am trying to make an app where i store data using firebase , the app listens for firebase firestore changes and pushes a notifications through local notifications, my issue is the notification works when the app is opened but the doesn't when the app is on the background
, is there a solution without using fire messaging push notifications? and a paid apple dev account?
I tried making a background service using flutter_background_services but i didn't manage to make it work .
here is my code for flutter notifications :
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';



class NotificationService {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin=FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  
  NotificationService() {
     initNotification();
  }

  Future<void> initNotification() async{
      AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings= const AndroidInitializationSettings("app_logo");
      var initialisationIos=DarwinInitializationSettings(
        options: <DarwinNotificationCategoryOption>{
            DarwinNotificationCategoryOption.hiddenPreviewShowTitle,
        },
    )
],requestSoundPermission: true,onDidReceiveLocalNotification:(id, title, body, payload)async {
        
      } ,requestAlertPermission: true,requestBadgePermission: true);

      var initialisationSettings=InitializationSettings(android: androidInitializationSettings,iOS: initialisationIos);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initialisationSettings,onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) {
        
      },);

  }




 

  notificationDetails() async{
      return const NotificationDetails(android: AndroidNotificationDetails(priority: Priority.high,sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("notification.mp3"),"channelId", "channelName",importance: Importance.max,)
      ,iOS:  DarwinNotificationDetails(sound: "notification.caf",presentSound: true));
  }

  Future showNotificatio({int id=0 ,String? title,String?body , String? payload}) async{
      return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id, title, body, await notificationDetails(),payload: payload);
  }
}

my Failed Background Service attempt :


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  );
  await initializeService();
  runApp(const MainApp());
    

}
bool firstSnapshot=true;

@pragma('vm:entry-point')

Future<bool> startFireBaseListener(ServiceInstance service) async{
    
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("journal").snapshots().listen((event) {

       if(firstSnapshot){
         firstSnapshot=false; 
         return;
       }
       
       final lastDoc= event.docChanges[event.docChanges.length-1];
       if(lastDoc.type==DocumentChangeType.added){
           NotificationService().showNotificatio(body: lastDoc.doc["body"],title: lastDoc.doc["title"]);
       }
      
      },);

      return true;
}


Future initializeService()async{

try{
     final flutterService=FlutterBackgroundService();

     await flutterService.configure(iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(autoStart: true,onBackground: (service) => startFireBaseListener(service),onForeground: (service) => startFireBaseListener(service),),
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(autoStart: true,autoStartOnBoot: true,onStart: (service) => startFireBaseListener(service), isForegroundMode: false,));

     await flutterService.startService();
     print("background service started");
}catch(e){
  print(e.toString());
}   
 
}



Firestore change listeners will not fire while your app is in the background on iOS.  If you need to send notifications while your app is in the background you will need to use push notifications.

@Paulw11 isn't there another way ? without a paid apple dev account?

Not that I can think of

It's not nothing to do with your account type. Having a paid account doesn't let your app do more things technically or architectural than without
